# Buying an Option with a premium lower than the Bid Price

Tags: call-options

For a share trading at $272, I placed an order to buy an option with Strike Price at $275. The Ask is $10 and The Bid is $9. I entered at $9.10 with expiration in Sep. The order has not been filled yet.

What happens if the bid is unsuccessful and still below strike price when it expires? And what happen if the bid is unsuccessful and the Strike Price is reached? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Have you bought the option, or are you still trying to buy it?

Comment: If you don't manage to buy the option, then nothing happens; your portfolio remains the same. Perhaps I have misunderstood the question. What exactly did you think would "happen"?

Comment: Sorry, I may not have phrase my question clearly. It is still not in my holdings. It shows under daily orders. What happen if the bidding price is too low?

Comment: @TannerSwett I think the title of the question needs to be fixed. "Buying an Option with a premium lower than the Bid Price" doesn't seem to be related to the body of the question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you enter a bid, and nobody takes it - absolutely nothing happens.

This applies to any and all instruments (options, futures, stocks, whatever).

It's quite normal that people put in lowball bids and just leave them sitting there.  If they fill - great.  If they don't fill, no harm done.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are talking about a call option here.

> What happens if the bid is unsuccessful and still below strike price when it expires?

If the bid is unsuccessful, then you would not own the option and the bid would expire with the option.  However, you need to be careful.  Shortly before the expiration, a savvy stock owner may fulfill your bid provided it is sufficiently out of the money.  You could be paying for an option with no time value and no intrinsic value.

> And what happen if the bid is unsuccessful and the Strike Price is
> reached?

You still don't own the option and it is likely the bid and ask prices will increase as the stock prices comes closer to the strike price.

I would advise against allowing bids to stand on options for more than a few hours.  The nature of options is quick trades and as such long term bids can really harm you.

Comment: Your second paragraph makes no sense to me.  An option that has  no time value and no intrinsic value has a value of zero.  It might have an ask price of 5 or 10 cents or something in that vicinity but what does any of this have to do with the OP's question? Even if he placed a GTC order to buy at $9.10, it would never get filled on the way to zero.

Comment: You know guys as I understand it: the OP is not even asking anything about options per se.  OP is apparently simply asking, what happens if you make a low bid (on anything) and it just sits there.

Comment: @Fattie - The OP is indeed asking about options but your comment is the big picture view in that it's applicable to any security.  You bid lower, you go on the order book.

Answer (score 0):

- $272 = share price
- $275 call (?) is $9.00 x $10.00

If you place an order to buy at $9.10 and you are the best bid then you'll get a trade execution if a counter party is willing to sell the contract to you at your $9.10 price.  If no one is willing to transact at that price then you do not buy the option and it doesn't matter what share price does subsequently because you have no position in the option.